# Rails 5 api, angular 4, user params not coming through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, parameters

I'm building an Angular 4/5 app using Rails 5 --api mode on the backend.  I'm not using any authentication yet.

Here's my User **user.ts**

```
export class User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  password_confirmation: string;
  admin: boolean;
  activated: boolean;

  constructor(name: string, email: string, password: string, confirmPassword: string, admin: boolean, activated: boolean){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.password_confirmation = confirmPassword;
    this.admin = admin;
    this.activated = activated;
  }
}
```

I am sending a post request to `/users` to the Rails controller `Users#create`.

My request payload looks like the following:

```
activated: true
admin: true
email: "me@example.com"
name: "Mike Glaz"
password: "password1"
password_confirmation: "password1"
```

when I `pry` into the rails controller`Users#create` and type `params` I see the following:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Mike Glaz", 
"email"=>"me@example.com", "password"=>"password1", 
"password_confirmation"=>"password1", "admin"=>true, 
"activated"=>true, "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"create", 
"user"=>{"name"=>"Mike Glaz", "email"=>"me@example.com", 
"admin"=>true, "activated"=>true}} permitted: false>
```

iinside my method `user_params` when I do `params.require(:user)` it comes back with

```
{"name"=>"Mike Glaz", "email"=>"me@example.com", "admin"=>true, "activated"=>true}
```

I can't figure out why `params` has 2 different sets of parameters and why `user` does not include the `password` and `password_confirmation`.

Inside `routes.rb` I have

```
resources :users
```

Comment: make sure `user_params` method has a pass and conf_pass

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what `pass` and `conf_pass` are...

Comment: It doesn't look like your posting the form data in the expected format. Can you provide the javascript that's making the post call? Alternatively, it appears that `params.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :activated)` would work in place of `params.require(:user)`.